# Integrating a $u$-substitution approach further

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm already at the second step of evaluating this integral. I already applied $u$-substitution from the original integral and it gave me $$ \int \frac { u }{{ 1+u^4 }} \,  du.$$

I'm not exactly sure how to move forward from this. As of now, my approach is to use u-sub again and let ${\bar u}$ = ${u^2}$ which gives me $$ \int \frac { 1 }{{ 2(1+\bar u^2) }} \,  d\bar u $$

and then I can extract the constant $1/2$ and simply solve for the integral which is just ${\tan^{-1} \bar u}$. I'm not sure if this the correct way to approach it though. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: This is arguably the best approach.

Comment: Your idea was unndoubtedly correct

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $\int\frac{udu}{1+u^4}$, you can define the new variable $w=u^2$ (as you correctly wrote) in order to have
$$\int \dfrac{udu}{1+u^4}=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{2udu}{1+(u^2)^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{dw}{1+w^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\arctan(w)+c=\dfrac{1}{2}\arctan(u^2)+c.$$
Note that $w=u^2\implies \dfrac{dw}{du}=2u$, so $dw=2udu$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 1+u^4 = (1+u \sqrt 2 + u^2) (1-u \sqrt 2 + u^2)$$